# How do I save a local copy of my data from LastPass?

Tags: backup, password-management, lastpass

Most online password managers are great. I've been using LastPass (with a varying degree of success.) It works fine in most cases when their site loads up. But it become a real pain when it does not.

So a while back I started using LastPass pocket app with a local copy of my data. I try to save a copy of my data on my PC every 3 months or so. Just as a backup of my passwords. (It's all encrypted in a file, so it's safe.)

Today though when I tried to load it up I got this error:

> ErrorCode=This component is no longer available. Use the LastPass
> browser extension or desktop app. Deprecated: 09/30/2020

[image]

So how am I supposed to get a copy of my data from LastPass now so that I can use it locally?

PS. I understand that LastPass has gone down the tubes since acquisition by LogmeIn, so no surprise there. What I'm wondering is if there's some third party app that can do this?

Comment: Have you done as instructed, i.e., "Use the LastPass browser extension or desktop app?"

Comment: @DrMoishePippik. Idk what it is. Can you link to it?

Comment: Look at the image you provided.